# Include Select All option in jquery mobile select (multiple)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, multi-select

I have a multiple `select` dropdown as below:

```
 <select name="sel" id="sel" data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="-1">All Options</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
```

When I select "All Options" it should select all the Options and when I deselect it , it should deselect all the options. And if I only deselect the "Option 1" or "Option 2", it should deselect the "All Options" also.

I need to implement this similar to the [bootstrap multiple select](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/). As in the example of "Multiselect with a 'Select all' option."

How to include the select all option in the jQuery Mobile Select?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you please share a jsfiddle link

Comment: In jQuery Mobile select, I need to add the select All option similar to bootstrap multiselect(http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/).

Comment: you mean http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#further-examples (second example)?

Comment: No. similar to the example "Multiselect with a 'Select all' option."

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996844/how-can-i-add-select-all-option-in-jquerymobile-1-4-2-custom-select/